# How to save the configuration after changing lines from a git config --edit

Tags: git

allow me to explain my query here.

I'm trying to reset all authors including my git-pairs

`git pair --reset` isn't working anymore. A documentation had advised me to do the configuration using `git config --edit`

I entered the command `git config --edit`

and removed the

`[user]` and `[git-pair]` values...

How can I save the configuration after? Should I hit something from the keyboard or what.

I just know how to insert stuffs in there by pressing Insert button from keyboard but I dont know how to save the config and go back to the command prompt earlier.

I want to save the new config file which is:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
        hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
~
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Assuming the editor in use is VI(M): hit <kbd>esc</kbd> to leave insert mode, then <kbd>:wq</kbd> to save and quit

Comment: Thank you so much. I should have research for VIM commands instead. Thanks.

Comment: How about in a Windows CLI (console)?

Comment: Ja, I tried using :quit, and VI(m) asks me, where do you wanna save?  I'm like, Umm...

Answer (score 1):

You edit it in the same way as you would edit a commit message. If you're not comfortable with the default editor, change it using the `EDITOR` environment variable. Also, you can directly edit your configuration file using an editor of your choice.